# How to add a value to a new column by referencing the values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  reason  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5 
 1  x1      100   15   10   20   25
 2  x1      15    16   14   10   10
 3  x4      10    50   40   30   25
 4  x3      12    15   60   5    1
 5  x1      80    15   10   20   25
 6  x1      15    19   84   10   10
 7  x4      90    40   90   30   25
 8  x4      12    85   60   50   10
```

The **xy** column must be filled with the value of the column names in the **reason** column. Let's look at the first row. The **reason column** shows our value **x1**. So our value in column **xy**, will be the value of x1 column in the first row. Like this:

```
id  reason  x1    x2   x3   x4   x5   xy
 1  x1      100   15   10   20   25   100
 2  x1      15    16   14   10   10   15
 3  x4      10    50   40   30   25   30
 4  x3      12    15   60   5    1    60
 5  x1      80    15   10   20   25   80
 6  x1      15    19   84   10   10   15
 7  x4      90    40   90   30   25   30
 8  x4      12    85   60   50   10   50
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear, please do add more details on logic part on how to get your expected output. Also please post your tried code in your question too, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't the row with `id=2` be 15 for `xy`?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope it became clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df["xy"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x["reason"]], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id reason   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5   xy
0   1     x1  100  15  10  20  25  100
1   2     x1   15  16  14  10  10   15
2   3     x4   10  50  40  30  25   30
3   4     x3   12  15  60   5   1   60
4   5     x1   80  15  10  20  25   80
5   6     x1   15  19  84  10  10   15
6   7     x4   90  40  90  30  25   30
7   8     x4   12  85  60  50  10   50
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
df['new'] = df.values[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df.reason)]
df
   id reason   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  new
0   1     x1  100  15  10  20  25  100
1   2     x1   15  16  14  10  10   15
2   3     x4   10  50  40  30  25   30
3   4     x3   12  15  60   5   1   60
4   5     x1   80  15  10  20  25   80
5   6     x1   15  19  84  10  10   15
6   7     x4   90  40  90  30  25   30
7   8     x4   12  85  60  50  10   50
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the new column like this:

```
xy = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4']
df['xy'] = xy
```

With `df` being the name of your dataframe. But your example of what that column should contain is very unclear. Also post the code you have tried.

You can access columns and rows in the dataframe very easily.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html
I assume you are using pandas.